# Intellij idea : Importing another pom as a module into a multi-module project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, intellij-idea

We have a multi-module project like this

```
<modules>
    <module>xxx</module>
    <module>another-pom.xml</module>
</modules>
```

here the second module is not actually a module name but its a pom , this is needed as per our requirement , in eclipse its not a problem , but in intelli, it says "cannot resolve symbol another-pom.xml" as a result the project dependency resolution is failing,

is there any known solution for this issue ?

Thanks

Comment: What version of IntelliJ? Does the project build when using Maven from the command line?

Comment: yes, command line 'mvn clean install' works anyway, the problem is with only IntelliJ

Comment: i am using intelliJ 14

Comment: Is the project defined by `another-pom.xml` open in IntelliJ?